# Eclipse freezes elementaryOs

Tags: elementary-os

Everytime I try to run eclipse, my system crashes, it just freezes the screen and I can't do anything. I've already installed the JDK and Eclipse from the official websites, exported the var JAVA_HOME and PATH (in path just added the path to the bin folder of the JDK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am on Elementary 0.3 Freya. Which version of Eclipse are you trying to run? If you don't mind Eclipse 3.8, you can just get it from apt-get with sudo apt-get install eclipse and it is quite stable and fast.

If you want Eclipse 4.0 or above, you will need to download the tar.gz from eclipse.org.

For some reason, when I try to execute eclipse inside a home directory (such as . /home/user/Downloads/eclipse/eclipse) I get the same problem that you are describing - my machine starts paging like crazy and freezes (and I have a Broadwell i5 CPU... 4g ram). I've increased the Java VM memory and paging sizes like some pages suggested but it still freezes.

But it worked for me (no more lag) when I followed these steps exactly

http://www.boerngen-schmidt.de/2014/08/installing-eclipse-ide-on-elementary-os-0-3/

Which is:

1. sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
2. download eclipse from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ (I downloaded Juno 4.2)
3. tar zxvf eclipse-SDK-4.2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz or whatever the file you downloaded
4. sudo mv eclipse /opt/
5. vi ~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop or with your favorite editor to have the following:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=4.4.0
   Name=Eclipse
   Comment=Eclipse IDE
   Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
   Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Categories=Development;Application
   ```
6. Then you can find your Eclipse desktop entry in Slingshot and launch it.

Good luck